# Why are my multiprocesses not starting without time.sleep in main?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have some background task that i want to start an be able to safely quit by user input.
To do that i have a thread in which a process pool with a continous task is started. There is a input lock to stop printing and to wait for user input and a event to stop the whole process.
What surprises me is that the processes seem to start and do their work if there is a time.sleep after the start of the thread with processpool (6th line in main).

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import threading as tr


def init(e, l):
    global stop_event
    global input_lock
    stop_event = e
    input_lock = l


def stupid_task(n):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        with input_lock:
            print(n)
        time.sleep(2)


def test_mng(n, event, lock):
    with mp.Pool(n, initializer=init, initargs=(event, lock,)) as p:
        print("before")
        p.map(stupid_task, range(1, n + 1))
        print("after")
        p.close()
        p.join()


def main():
    i_lock = mp.Lock()
    s_event = mp.Event()
    thread = tr.Thread(target=test_mng, args=(3, s_event, i_lock))
    init(s_event,i_lock)
    thread.start()
    time.sleep(1) # if this line is commented out only "before" is printed
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        input("")
        with input_lock:
            print("stopped")
            eingabe = input("type q to quit")
            if eingabe == "q":
                stop_event.set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I ask myself what is stopping the process pool from doing it's work. Do i do something fundamentally wrong? The time.sleep seems a little bit hacky.

Comment: Then `input()` function is locking the main process...

Comment: but the processes are started before. Are they not independent?

Comment: I tested running other functions in the thread and it all works fine. Only when i try to run the pool it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I my opinion, you are running your script from an IDE (like PyCharm), but not from the Console. Your IDE is catching the keyboard events.

You can simplify the processing:

- The main process can wait for the user input,
- The thread can do the "stupid task".

Here is a possible solution:

```
# coding: utf-8
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading as tr
import time

stop_event = None


def init(event):
    global stop_event
    stop_event = event


def stupid_task(n):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        print(n)
        time.sleep(2)


def test_mng(n, event):
    with mp.Pool(n, initializer=init, initargs=(event,)) as p:
        print("before")
        p.map(stupid_task, range(1, n + 1))
        print("after")
        p.close()
        p.join()


def main():
    print("type 'q' <ENTER> to quit")
    s_event = mp.Event()
    init(s_event)

    thread = tr.Thread(target=test_mng, args=(3, s_event,))
    thread.start()

    while not stop_event.is_set():
        c = input("")
        if c in "qQ":
            stop_event.set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Running it outside the IDE went perfect. Will try that in the future before asking questions. And thanks a lot for the simplification. I just noticed i don't realy need the Lock for my usecase.